# Авторизация в Телеграм без использования консоли

Tags: python, api, pyrogram

Мне необходимо реализовать **Авторизацию в Телеграм с помощью
собственного Телеграм-Бота** (использую **aiogram** и **pyrogram**)

***Проблема***:
Когда пытаюсь авторизоваться:

```
client = Client(api_name, api_id, api_hash, phone_number=phone_number)
```

В терминал выводится такой текст:

```
Welcome to Pyrogram (version 2.0.99)
Pyrogram is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. Licensed
under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License v3.0 (LGPL-3.0).

The confirmation code has been sent via Telegram app
The confirmation code is invalid
Enter confirmation code:
```

И я должен **ввести код, который выслал Телеграм.** Но как мне это сделать, если я **не имею доступа к терминалу**? Я хотел бы **код отправить Боту, и чтобы Бот попробовал ввести этот Код и при этом, желательно узнать, верный ли оказался код, или нет**

Я бы мог эмулировать введение **input()**, но это же будет "костылем"

Подскажите пожалуйста, может есть более хорошее решение данной проблемы?